# Re-plotting Jqplot on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jqplot

I am using this code to create a Jqplot using the AJAX JSON Data Renderer.  it is all working ok.  I have a button on the page which allows a user to enter a new value (updated via ajax).  This is being stored into the DB (same place as the json data is coming from).

I would like the jqplot to be refreshed (i.e. check the ajax source) again when the button is pushed and the new value has been added to the DB.

I have tried a few methods which either dont update the graph or plot the graph on top of each other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
  // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
  // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
  var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
      // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
      // will return before the data is fetched
      async: false,
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
        ret = data;
      }
    });
    return ret;
  };

  // The url for our json data
  var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

  // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
  // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
  // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
      unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    }
  });
});
```

Assuming I would need to add the jqplot into a function and destroy the old plot and then call the function on success? - Cant quite get things working correctly using that method though.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [jqPlot.reDraw](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.redraw). And I really suggest that you don't use the async:false ajax request, you can make it work by moving the plot2 = $.jqplot piece inside of the success function of the ajax request.

Comment: redraw is used primarily with zooming.

Comment: The ajax JSON Data Renderer is what jqplot recommend. http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php  I have multiple charts running on the same page that use the same dataRenderer. SUrely would get messey if it was done on the ajax success?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try re-plotting the chart?

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
      title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
      dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
      dataRendererOptions: {
      unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    }
});

plot2.replot();
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Anish